# Linear Recursion reverse the array

Tags: c++

Can not figure out why my recursion function does not work?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int ReverseArray(int* A, int i, int j);

int main()
{
    int j = 10;
    int i = 0;
    int *b = new int[j];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        b[i] = i;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) //just to compare the old and new array
        cout << b[i] << endl; //just to compare the 
    for(int i = 0; i <= j; i++)
    cout << ReverseArray(b,i,j) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int ReverseArray(int* A, int i, int j)
{
    if (i <= j)
    {
        swap(A[i], A[j]); 
        ReverseArray(A, i + 1, j - 1);

    }

    return A[i];
```

This should return

> 10,9,8....

but it returns

> 10,0,9,1...

I don't get why its happening

Comment: Fyi, you can do this with just an array base and length, using pointer arithmetic and descending the length in the recursive call. [**See it live**](http://ideone.com/8LPUsq). Alternatively, using [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) would be the easiest way, but I doubt that would be a legitimate solution for your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You have a double loop, once here:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= j; i++)
     cout << ReverseArray(b,i,j) << endl;
```

and once here:

```
ReverseArray(A, i + 1, j - 1);
```

Calling a function recursively is equivalent to looping over it. To reverse a list, you only need to loop over it once, and what you've done is the equivalent of a doubly-nested loop. So let's get rid of

```
for(int i = 0; i <= j; i++)
```

and change

```
cout << ReverseArray(b,i,j) << endl;
```

to just

```
ReverseArray(b,i,j);
```

Then you are only reversing b, nothing else. To print, just loop from 0 to 10 and print each element.

Also, unrelated, but keep in mind that the code as you have it right now touches memory that has not been allocated to the heap.

```
int *b = new int[j];
```

creates j (here, 10) ints, at the physical memory locations b, b + 1, b + 2, ..., b + 9. b[i] then gets the memory held at b + i, that is, it gets *(b + i). Several of your loops try to do things with b[10], and there has not been enough memory allocated for it. This will result in undefined behaviour (i.e. many different things can happen depending on your compiler and the state of your computer). With 'system("pause");' removed (which shouldn't affect code execution) on my machine, this gave me a memory allocation for that reason.

Solution here is to either have

```
int *b = new int[j+1];
```

or replace all your <= signs with <.